# SQL - Return next to go company from one-to-many relationship

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need help with writing a query I am stuck on.

I am basically needing the list of CompanySteps that their “CompanyStepCompanyCode” is pending, meaning not assigned as the current “CompanyNextGoCompany”. So they are awaiting for their turn in the series of step for a report.

There is a one to many relationship between the Company to CompanyStep. One company with a “CompanyWorkNumber” can have however many “CompanyStepStepOrder”.
Here is a little snapshot of what data looks like. Sorry for bad format, not sure how to create good tables here.

```
+-------------------+----------------------+------------------------+----------------------+----------+
| CompanyWorkNumber | CompanyStepStepOrder | CompanyStepCompanyCode | CompanyNextGoCompany | lastStep |
+-------------------+----------------------+------------------------+----------------------+----------+
|           8126599 |                    1 | COBML                  | COBML                |        1 |
|           8126599 |                    2 | LASHW                  | COBML                |        2 |
|           8126599 |                    3 | UXEBC                  | COBML                |        3 |
|           8256656 |                    1 | ARKHA                  | COBML                |        1 |
|           8256656 |                    2 | COMSCH                 | COBML                |        2 |
|           8256656 |                    3 | LASHW                  | COBML                |        3 |
|           8356657 |                    1 | ARKHA                  | COBML                |        1 |
|           8356657 |                    2 | COMSCH                 | COBML                |        2 |
|           8356657 |                    3 | LASHW                  | COBML                |        3 |
|           8656658 |                    1 | ARKHA                  | COBML                |        1 |
|           8656658 |                    2 | TNSRA                  | COBML                |        2 |
|           8886659 |                    1 | LASHW                  | LASHW                |        1 |
|           8886659 |                    2 | UXEBC                  | LASHW                |        2 |
|           8886659 |                    3 | LASHW                  | LASHW                |        3 |
+-------------------+----------------------+------------------------+----------------------+----------+
```

So for CompanyWorkNumber 8126599, I am wanting the row LASHW to return because the current “CompanyStepCompanyCode(COBML)” is assigned as next to Go “CompanynextGoCompany(COBML)” is still assigned their code, that means they haven’t finished their step yet. So LASHW is awaiting their turn. It does not matter if LASHW is the very next Company to go or however many down the steps tree, just as long as it’s after the current step’s CompanyCode.

So for 8886659, if you notice LASHW is assigned as the first Company to proceed with Step, but they are also the last on that WorkNumber, so for that one, “CompanyStepStepOrder” 3 should return.

The “lastStep” is just a Partion By I have done. I’m not sure if it can be used for this.
The companies I am looking for awaiting next to go come from another table, around 300 of them. And I’m looking to Join these 3 tables so that I can grab the information as one SELECT.

So I am thinking of having a WITH () maybe….?
I’ve just been messing around with different queries, but nothing really solid yet. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to proceed?

And if someone will let me know how to make a table here, that would be great:)

This query builds out an in memory version of the above so that you can work with the data.

```
WITH SRC
(
    CompanyWorkNumber
,   CompanyStepStepOrder
,   CompanyStepCompanyCode
,   CompanyNextGoCompany
,   lastStep
) AS
(
    SELECT 8126599, 1, 'COBML', 'COBML', 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 8126599, 2, 'LASHW', 'COBML', 2
    UNION ALL SELECT 8126599, 3, 'UXEBC', 'COBML', 3
    UNION ALL SELECT 8256656, 1, 'ARKHA', 'COBML', 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 8256656, 2, 'COMSCH', 'COBML', 2
    UNION ALL SELECT 8256656, 3, 'LASHW', 'COBML', 3
    UNION ALL SELECT 8356657, 1, 'ARKHA', 'COBML', 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 8356657, 2, 'COMSCH', 'COBML', 2
    UNION ALL SELECT 8356657, 3, 'LASHW', 'COBML', 3
    UNION ALL SELECT 8656658, 1, 'ARKHA', 'COBML', 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 8656658, 2, 'TNSRA', 'COBML', 2
    UNION ALL SELECT 8886659, 1, 'LASHW', 'LASHW', 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 8886659, 2, 'UXEBC', 'LASHW', 2
    UNION ALL SELECT 8886659, 3, 'LASHW', 'LASHW', 3
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    SRC AS S
```

Comment: Please learn to format your tables when you post data. It was too difficult to read your OP.

Comment: thanks for formatting